# Should we add the eyepiece tag to all questions that are about eyepieces? Or instead delete it since tagging would be a hopeless, quixotic quest?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tagging

I've just asked [How does eyepiece exit pupil diameter affect image clarity and viewing experience?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/46969/7982) and added the [eyepiece](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eyepiece) tag. It turns out this is only the 2nd question to use this tag, the first was only several months ago.

The search `eyepiece is:question` currently [returns 141 questions](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=eyepiece+is%3Aquestion) and a lot of these are squarely about eyepieces and are great candidates for this tag.

I estimate that **roughly 50 questions** are really about eyepieces, including those about Barlow lenses or image inversion prisms that would accompany an eyepiece.

The mature tags [telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telescope), [amateur-observing](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amateur-observing) and [optics](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optics) all sort-of cover this class of question as well, but adding a specific eyepiece tag to questions specifically about eyepieces seems helpful to the extent that any tag is helpful.

Alternatively, if we don't add the tag to proper eyepiece questions, I think we should delete it for two reasons:

1. Tag hygiene: tags should be either healthy and useful or gone. Dead tags should be sent to the cornfield so they don't clutter or end up misused/misapplied.
2. An existing tag which is absent for many question for which it applies is deceptive, it can lead people to think we don't have many questions on that topic.

**Question:** Should we add the eyepiece tag to all questions that are about eyepieces? Or instead delete it since tagging would be a hopeless, quixotic quest?

I'm happy to go ahead and *over the next several weeks* add [eyepiece](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eyepiece) to questions specifically about the eyepiece end of an amateur telescope (includes Barlow lens questions and those about eyepiece projection) using the usual 10 or 20 question per week retagging so as not to flood the active queue unduly.

But I just want to see what folks think first.

Comment: I say: go for it!

Answer (score 3):

Voting on the question is currently +3/-0 and there's an affirmative comment with two upvotes as well.

If there are no further objections, I'll go ahead and start adding the [eyepiece](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eyepiece) tag to the estimated 50 questions where it's appropriate. As usual I'll do it in smaller groups so as not to overwhelm the active queue.

> I estimate that roughly 50 questions are really about eyepieces, including those about Barlow lenses or image inversion prisms that would accompany an eyepiece.

There will be a few about eyepiece projection and I think those can be included as well.